# How to use .indexyear in xts package

Tags: r, date, xts

I'm trying to use the `.indexyear` function in the xts package, but can't get my head around how it's supposed to be used.

Below are some code, you can see that the `.indexyear` returns `112, 113, 114, 115` for the years `2012, 2013, 2014, 2015`. I want to see if a certain year exists in the xts object index, so how do I make `2012 %in% .indexyear(a)` equal to `TRUE`?

Code

```
Browse[1]> index(a)
[1] "2012-12-30 00:00:00 CET" "2013-12-30 00:00:00 CET" "2014-12-30 00:00:00 CET" "2015-12-30 01:00:00 CET"

Browse[1]> .indexyear(a)
[1] 112 113 114 115

Browse[1]> 2014 %in% .index(a) # should actually be TRUE!
[1] FALSE

Browse[1]> 113 %in% .indexyear(a)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `2014 %in% .index(a)` should only be `TRUE` if your index contains a time that really is 2014 seconds after the epoch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.index*` functions basically wrap the components of the `POSIXlt` class. So see the *Details* section of `?POSIXlt`, which says:

> 'year' years since 1900.

So you need to add 1900 to the output of `.indexyear` to get what you want.

```
a <- structure(1:4, .Dim = c(4L, 1L), index = structure(c(1356847200, 1388383200,
  1419919200, 1451458800), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
  class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
  tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")
2014 %in% (.indexyear(a)+1900)
# [1] TRUE
```